# Katalon dynamic xpath on script mode

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

I want to create a dynamic test object.

Here's my test object's xpath:

```
(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='${username}'])[1]/following::span[1]
```

I want to replace `${username}` dynamically in my script. Here's what i've tried:

```
WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Page_CICIL_adminDashboard/span_Dash', [('username'):varEmail]), 3)
```

but it throws `element not found` like this:

```
com.kms.katalon.core.webui.exception.WebElementNotFoundException: Web element with id: 'Object Repository/Page_CICIL_adminDashboard/span_Dash' located by 'By.xpath: (.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='${username}'])[1]/following::span[1]' not found)
```

Looks like the `${username}` variable wasn't replaced by my value correctly.. can you please suggest how to do it correctly?

Comment: Which option did you use? 
 - XPath
 - Attribute
 - CSS

Comment: @TonyBui i'm using xpath

Comment: It is a known bug, and we are fixing it. In the meantime, you could use the Attribute:
 - Click Attribute
 - Add a new item: 'xpath' with the value you used.

Comment: @TonyBui ah it's good to know.. btw i found temporary solution for this issue on my answer below :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found a (temporary) workaround for this :D

i fully write the TestObject using script like this

```
String xpath_spanDash = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='" + varEmail + "'])[1]/following::span[1]"
println '>>> the span dash xpath is: ' + xpath_spanDash
TestObject toSpanDash = new TestObject("span_Dash2")
toSpanDash.addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, xpath_spanDash)
```

and verify the element using this way

```
// verifying elements
WebUI.verifyElementPresent(toSpanDash, 3)
```

Comment: Well, it is a workaround... I use something like this for the definition of most test objects because I think this is a better approach than using the object repository.

Comment: @MateMrše is it better to treat all out Test Objects like this btw?

Comment: That is how I treat them, but I guess it will depend on your preferences.